# Find largest permutation less than a certain value

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Here is a certain programming problem that I can't seem to figure out how to do.

> Given two integers `a` and `b`, find the largest
>   permutation of the digits of `a` that is less than `b`.

Is there any way I can use the `next_permutation` function in `c++`? Or, should I use some form of dynamic programming to solve this?

I've tried testing all permutations of `a` using the next_permutation function, but because the size of the integers can be up to 10^18, 18! is way too large for this to be feasible. **Is there any way I can cut down on the time? If not, how should I go about using dynamic programming for this kind of problem?**

I'd greatly appreciate any kind of help for this. Thank you guys so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to find all combinations of `a` in order to do this.

Let's assume `a` is 'world', and `b` is 'hello'. You can find the largest character in `a` that is less than or equal to the first character of `b`. In this case, you find 'd' in `a`. This is the biggest character you can start with for your permutations of `a`, so you should start with it. Because 'd' is strictly smaller than 'h', you can just rank all remaining characters in `a` from biggest to smallest, and you get 'dwrol'.

If the first characters are the same, say `a` is 'world', and `b` is 'like', you continue the process with the remaining characters in `a` after the first character and compare to the second character of `b`. In this example, the first character you pick in `a` is 'l'. You have 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd' left. Then you pick the biggest character that is less than the second character in 'like', which is 'd', then you repeat the previous process and get 'ldwro'.

Edit:

For the edited question (permutations of digits instead of characters), the idea is the same. If `a` has more digits than `b`, your permutations of `a` are always greater than `b` (let's assume no 0 in `a` for now). Then you know there is no solution. If `a` has less digits than `b`, just find the largest permutation of a because a can never be greater than `b`. If they are of the same length, then it's the same as doing it lexicographically.

If there are 0s in `a`, just remove them until you run out of 0s or a has the same number of digits as `b`, then you continue the process above.

Comment: Sorry, but I kind of rephrased the question. Really sorry :((

Comment: The idea is the same. If `a` has more digits than `b`, your permutations of `a` are always greater than `b` (let's assume no 0 in `a` for now). Then you know there is no solution. If `a` has less digits than `b`, just find the largest permutation of `a` because `a` can never be greater than `b`. If they are of the same length, then it's the same as doing it lexicographically.

Comment: If there are 0s in `a`, just remove them until you run out of 0s or `a` has the same number of digits as `b`, then you continue the process above.

Comment: Okay thanks...I'm just going to accept your answer although it's technically in your comments XD thank you so much!!

Comment: Just edited the answer to reflect the change. Glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

Going over all permutations would take too long. Just be greedy instead.

The case of lexicographical comparison is simple (this was the original version of the question):

For each position in turn, pick the largest element of `a` not used yet, that still makes `a` lexicographically less than `b`.

Numbers are a bit more complex, because the rules for comparing numbers are slightly different. Fortunately, it can be easily reduced to lexicographical comparison.

- Strip the leading zeros from `b`, it will make things a bit simpler.
- If the lengths of `a` and `b` are equal, then it is the same as the previous case - lexicographical comparison is the same as numerical comparison.
- If the length of `b` is less than `a`, just add leading zeros to `b` to match the length of `a` - back to lexicographical comparison.
- If the length of `a` is less than `b`, and `b` has no leading zeros (we just stripped them). This guarantees that `a` is smaller than `b`. So we can just pick the largest permutation by sorting the digits starting from the largest first.

Comment: Hmm sorry I think I phrased the question incorrectly I'll edit it.

Comment: Now it is integers instead of strings. How would I account for like the lengths of the numbers? Like for example 215 > 52 but 52 is less than 215 lexicographically...

Answer (score 1):

Agree with previous answers
Here is a piece of code using std::set based bag-of-char representation

```
#include<iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

    std::string greatest_permutation(const std::string &s, const std::string &limit) {
        std::string result;
        std::set<char> bag;
        std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(),
             std::insert_iterator<std::set<char> >(bag, bag.begin()));
        for (int j=0; j<limit.size(); ++j) {
            std::set<char>::iterator i = bag.upper_bound(limit[j]);
            if (i == bag.begin()) // no more chars available
                return result;
            else
                result += *--i;
            bag.erase(i);
        }
    return result;
    }

    int main() {
        std::cout<<
        greatest_permutation("abcdefghi", "cfhuiigwuioiiom")
        <<std::endl;
    }
```