# Given integers X and Y, how do you find the largest permutation of X that is less than or equal to Y?

Tags: algorithm, permutation

```
Given two positive integers X and Y, find the largest permutation of X
that is less than or equal to Y. Return the largest permutation that is
less than or equal to Y as an integer. If there is no permutation of X
that is less than or equal to Y, return -1.

Example 1:
Input: X = 123, Y = 321
Output: 321

Example 2:
Input: X = 1733, Y = 3311
Output: 3173

Example 3:
Input: X = 999, Y = 111
Output: -1
```

Got this problem for an online assessment earlier yesterday, couldn't find an efficient solution for it and have been thinking about it but still can't think of the right approach. I first tried greedy, in which I would iterate Y from left to right and I create a permutation of X by appending the largest digit in X that is less than or equal to the digit in Y. But for X = 1733 and Y = 3311, my implementation would return -1 because the greedy algorithm rearranged X to 3317. So I turned to recursion, but as you'd expect this very quickly reached stack limit.

I've read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48313037/find-largest-permutation-less-than-a-certain-value) that seems to discuss a similar problem, but I believe the top solution fails for example 2. How do you approach this problem?

Comment: How does your question differ from the one you linked to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48313037/find-largest-permutation-less-than-a-certain-value ? Looks the same to me.

Comment: Please share more details. How is this problem related to programming?

Comment: "I believe the top solution fails for example 2" Since the question seams to be the same, I would implement it and test it. If it really fails that would be a very helpful counter-example for the answer in the other thread.

Comment: All the answers in the other thread are proposing a greedy algorithm. That means that for every digit, find the largest digit in X that is less than or equal to the corresponding one in Y. The OP has done that, and came up with 3317 (because the second 3 fits this algorithm) but in this case the greedy algorithm doesn't work. So we need to either continue with this question as the other one has wrong answers, or comment on the wrong answers in the other question to point out their mistake. However, those answers are more than 3 years old.

Comment: I would not expect recursion to reach the stack limit. In the case of 4 digits, there are just 24 permutations to be tried and this can be done with 4 recursion levels !

Comment: I guess a naive solution would be to use dichotomy along with an [nth_permutation](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/more_itertools/more.html#nth_permutation) function to directly generate the nth permutation.

Comment: @Stef: you need a fast way to generate the Nth permutation for given N.

Comment: @Stef: we can safely treat the multiset as a set. In case there are many equal digits we will be doing useless work (there is no point permuting them), but we will find a correct solution anyway.

Comment: @stef: mh, Houston, we have a problem in case of equal digits: 112
121
112
121
211
211. This is not increasing.

Comment: @Stef Linear time to generate the Nth permutation of a set is hard to believe. For example `more_itertools.nth_permutation` isn't linear, both because of the cost of `list.pop` and because of the cost of operating on very large numbers (remember they reached the stack limit, so their input numbers probably have 1000 digits or more). Is your statement incorporating that in these sets here, there are at most ten different values?

Comment: @KellyBundy: with thousand digits, a direct solution is just intractable. But most of the digits will be repeating, making the problem different.

Comment: @KellyBundy: by the way, I don't see why 1000 digits would overflow the stack. (See earlier comment.)

Comment: @KellyBundy Yeaaaaah I'm going back to bed now.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Oops, I usually only read Python questions, where 1000 is the default recursion limit. Didn't notice this isn't one. But I think most other languages typically have no issue with deeper recursion, so I still stand by my assumption that they have lengths of 1000 or more.

Comment: @KellyBundy: from the quote "this very quickly reached stack limit" I infer that the OP made it wrong.

Comment: @YvesDaoust That's possible, and that's why I said they "probably" have such large inputs, but I find the large-inputs explanation more likely. Too bad they abandoned their question instead of responding to your comment about this.

Comment: Greedy works if you 1) stop the first time your output perm has a lower digit than Y, and append all remaining digits in descending order, and 2) on reaching an impasse, unwind greedy moves until you can replace a digit with a smaller digit, then proceed as (1).

Answer (score 2):

A recursive solution.

Sort the digits of X decreasingly. Then, as long as you find no solution

- take in turn every digit in X that is not larger than the leading digit of Y;

  - if those digits are equal, recurse on X less this digit and the tail of Y;
  - if the digit of X is smaller (or X is empty), you are done;
  - if there is no such digit, you reached a dead-end.

This works because you are trying the permutations of X by decreasing value.

```
321 vs. 321
    3 21 vs. 3 21
        21 vs. 21
            1 vs. 1
                Done

7331 vs. 3311
    3 731 vs. 3 311
        3 71 vs. 3 11
            1 7 vs. 1 1
                Dead end
        1 73 vs. 3 11
            Done

999 vs. 111
    Dead end
```

---

A non-recursive efficient solution, hinted by @Stef.

The permutations of X can be ordered increasingly by sorting the digits then picking every first digit and recursing on the remaining ones. This established a bijection between the permutations and the integers in `[0, d!)` for `d` digits.

For an integer `m`, you can retrieve the corresponding permutation using a conversion from the factorial basis (take the quotient by `(d-1)!` and proceed recursively with the remainder). This takes `d` operations, and you can compare the permutation to `Y` in `O(d)` operations.

Now just implement a dichotomic search on the `d!` permutations, which takes `O(d.log(d!)) = O(d².log(d)))` operations.

---

**Update:** the second solution only works for distinct digits otherwise the permutations do not yield increasing numbers. I hope that there is a workaround.

Comment: @Stef: you are quite right, I played the algorithm wrongly.

Comment: Also I would say "a backtracking solution" rather than "a recursive solution".

Comment: @Stef: backtracking recursive. :-)

Comment: @Stef: you need to stack lists, I would certainly go for a recursive solution.

Comment: Why do you call the second solution efficient if it's O(d².log(d)))?

Comment: @Dave: what do you think about the backtracking method ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust It's good. I think it's logically equivalent to my answer though I don't express mine as a recursion. It's probably worth mentioning in your answer that you hit a dead end at most once; if it can be recovered from then you're done, and if not then there's no solution. If you also use counting sort for your first step, this is linear.

Comment: @Dave: no, I mean from the efficiency standpoint.

Comment: Your recursive solution is linear in the number of digits, so O(d), assuming you use a counting sort in the first step.

Answer (score 0):

If X has more digits then there is no solution. If Y has more digits then a descending sort of the digits of X is the solution. Assuming X and Y have the same number of digits:

Put the digits of X in a counting hash.

For each digit of Y going in descending order (left-to-right), take the max digit of X that isn't greater than it and use that in your permutation.

If you ever place a digit lower than its counterpart in Y, place all remaining digits in descending order.

If there ever isn't a non-greater digit available then do the following: repeatedly unwind your prior move until you get to a digit where a lower digit was available. Select the max such lower digit. Then, all remaining digits can be placed in descending order from the map. If there is no such digit (where a lower digit could have been chosen) then there is no solution.

If you get through all the digits then you've produced the max solution.

This is linear in the number of digits if this is limited to base 10. If your base can vary, this is O(num_digits * base)

---

Here's Ruby code for this.

```
def get_perm(x, y)
  # hist keeps a count of each of the digits of x
  hist = Hash.new 0; x.digits.each { |d| hist[d] += 1 }
  
  # output_digits is the answer we're building
  output_digits = []
  
  y_digits = y.digits
  x_digits = x.digits
  
  # If x has fewer digits then all permutations are good so pick the largest
  if x.digits.length < y.digits.length
    9.downto(0) do |digit|
      output_digits += [digit] * hist[digit]
    end
    return output_digits
  end
    
  # If y has fewer digits then no permutation is good, return -1
  if y.digits.length < x.digits.length
    return -1
  end

  # parse the digits of y

  (y_digits.length - 1).downto(0) do |i|
    cur_y_digit = y_digits[i]
    
    # use the current digit of y if possible
    if hist[cur_y_digit] > 0
      hist[cur_y_digit] -= 1
      output_digits.append(cur_y_digit)
      return output_digits if i == 0
      
    # otherwise, use the largest smaller digit available if possible
    else
      (cur_y_digit - 1).downto(0) do |smaller_digit|
        if hist[smaller_digit] > 0
          # place the smaller digit, then all remaining digits in descending order
          hist[smaller_digit] -= 1
          output_digits.append(smaller_digit)
          9.downto(0) do |digit|
            output_digits += [digit] * hist[digit]
          end
          return output_digits
        end
      end
      
      # If we make it here then no digit was available; we need to unwind moves until we
      # can replace a digit of our solution with a smaller digit
      
      smallest_digit = hist.keys.min
      while i < (y.digits.length - 1) do
        i += 1
        cur_y_digit = y_digits[i]
        cur_unwound_digit = output_digits.pop
        hist[cur_unwound_digit] += 1
        smallest_digit = [smallest_digit, cur_unwound_digit].min
        if cur_y_digit > smallest_digit
          (cur_y_digit - 1).downto(smallest_digit) do |d|
            if hist[d] >= 1
              output_digits.append(d)
              hist[d] -= 1
              9.downto(0) do |digit|
                output_digits += [digit] * hist[digit]
              end
              return output_digits
            end
          end
        end
      end
      return -1
    end
  end
end
```

Outputs for OP sample cases:

```
> get_perm(123, 321)
=> [3, 2, 1]
> get_perm(1733, 3311)
=> [3, 1, 7, 3]
> get_perm(999, 111)
=> -1
```

Comment: @KellyBundy I added a sentence: "If you ever place a digit lower than its counterpart in Y, place all remaining digits in descending order."

Comment: @KellyBundy Added code to execute this approach

Answer (score -1):

If `Z` is the answer, and the numbers have `n` digits, you can show that there is an index `i` such that `Z[:i] = Y[:i]`, `Z[i]<Y[i]`, and `Z[i+1:]` is as large as possible given digits of `X \ Z[:i+1]` (I use python array slice notation, and the last expression means "the set of digits of X minus those already chosen in Z up to i+1").

Given this, you can easily loop over each candidate `i`, and efficiently check if it's feasible to chose such `i` as in above. The solution is with the largest possible `i`.

The solution should be O(n*log(n)).

I'll leave the proof and implementation details, as I understand it's a homework :)

Comment: (didn't downvote this) Z=Y is allowed, in which case there is no Z[i]<Y[i]. Where does the log(n) come from?

Comment: It was implied that this would be catched by the case `i=n`, the first condition is met, the second is not relevant, and  the `Z[i+1:]` is empty; in this case it's the largest feasible `i`, so the algorithm returns the correct answer. In order to quickly return the largest possible number with digits from `Z[i+1:]`, you need to sort them in reverse order, which takes O(n*log(n)), although you can use counting sort (i.e. radix sort) to achieve O(n) but I thought OP probably didn't need such optimizations.

Comment: For i=n, Y[i] doesn't even exist. If you wrote the code, it'd raise an index error. If you sort the suffix and do that for every prefix, that sounds like overall O(n² log n).

Comment: Yes, you need to treat it as a special case, which is why I said I left implementation details and didn't write the code, but replacing `Z[i]<Y[i]` by `(i==n or Z[i]<Y[i])` isn't such a hard thing to figure out by yourself for OP... For the complexity you only need to sort the suffix for the index `i_opt` that is maximal, as it's only useful to construct the answer and not to check if it's possible; so you will do it only once, hence the O(n log n).